# QF-3 monoid algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, semigroups-and-monoids

A finite dimensional algebra $A$ is called QF-3 in case the injective envelope of the regular module is projective. For example all Frobenius algebras are QF-3.
Given a monoid algebra $kG$ of a finite monoid $G$, is there a nice characterisation when this algebra is $QF-3$?
Are there known ("natural") classes of monoid algebras that are QF-3 but not selfinjective?

Comment: Can you give a non trivial example that is not self injective?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Take a Nakayama algebra, so a quiver algebra with a directed line or circle as a quiver (and admissible releations). This is selfinjective iff the relations are $I=J^r$ and the quiver is a circle.

Comment: You can build a monoid algebra whose basic algebra is of that sort but I don't think anybody has thought much about this condition on monoid algebras.